# Is Zero Knowledge Proof part of Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I saw a number of articles talking about HL and ZKP but I was unsure if that is planned or actually implemented. I saw in the docs that version 1.4 is current but AWS has 1.2 implemented. Articles did not always state the versions and it was not that clear.

Has anyone the current status of ZKP and HL Fabric?

Answer (score 3):

Fabric 1.3 and later have limited support for ZKP; it is only use for anonymous / unlinkable credentials when using Identity Mixer credentials.  This allow clients to submit unlinkable transactions from an identity perspective.

There has been research into using ZKP for other types of transactions, but no concrete release plans.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Fabric 1.3 and later versions are providing privacy preserving attribute based authentication through Identity Mixer components. It is integrated into the Membership Service Provider (MSP) services. Identity Mixer is a cryptographic protocol suite for strong privacy-preserving authentication, signatures, and transfer of certified attributes.

Identity Mixer system allow for efficient zero-knowledge proofs (ZKP) of possession of a signature and the corresponding attributes. It does not reveal the signature and (selected) attribute values themselves, but only prove that the signature on some attributes is valid.

There are three actors involved in an Identity Mixer flow: user, issuer, and verifier. Following are the components in the implemented approach.

- The Fabric SDK is the API for the user.
- Fabric provides two possible Identity Mixer issuers: 
  Fabric CA for production environments or development, and the 'idemixgen' tool for development environments.
- The verifier is an Idemix MSP in Fabric.

The Identity Mixer implementation in the Fabric SDK can be found in the following GitHub repository.

[Identity Mixer in Fabric SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/tree/master/src/main/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/sdk/identity)

There is a stand alone implementations of Identity Mixer in the following GitHub repository.

[IBM Cloud Identity Mixer Issuer Verifier](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/idemix-issuer-verifier)